# docker swarm init --advertise-addr when IP address randomly changes

Tags: docker

I want to try out the `docker swarm` abilities.

When I run the command `docker swarm init`, I get the error message:

```
could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces (1.1.1.1 on enp89s0 and 2.2.2.2 on eno2) - specify on with the --advertise-addr
```

So then I tried this the command `docker swarm init --advertise-addr eno2`, but this gave the error:

```
Error response from daemon: interface eno2 has more than one IPv6 address (1111:1111::1111:1111:1111:1111 and 2222::2222:2222:2222:2222)
```

I have an additional challenge which is, my IPv6 and IPv4 addresses randomly change at times.  I'd prefer to run the `docker swarm init` with arguments that don't mention any specific ip address.  Can I start docker swarm using only network interface name and/or other constant property names of my network?

And anyone know if docker swarm will be stable in the midst of changing ip addresses?

Comment: any updates about this ??

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the output of the error message, I deleted one of the addresses reported off my network interface with:

**ip addr del ip_address dev interface**

For example to delete an extra ip_address reported:
**ip addr del 2600:5555:1234:2468::A1A1/128 dev enp2s0**

The problem was was solved. Check output of **ip addr**

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to:

> Because manager nodes are meant to be a stable component of the
> infrastructure, you should use a fixed IP address for the advertise
> address to prevent the swarm from becoming unstable on machine reboot.

Read this doc: [Configure the manager to advertise on a static IP address](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#configure-the-manager-to-advertise-on-a-static-ip-address)